# Emptying (a) Card Deck(s) in Java

Tags: java

I am Looking for some insight on how to make my card game know when the decks I have created have run out of cards.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardDealer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Shuffle!");

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        Map<Integer, Deck> decks = new HashMap<Integer, Deck>();

        int deckNum = getNumberOfDecks(console);
        int cardNum = getNumberOfCards(console);

        String readString = console.nextLine();
        while(readString!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(readString);
            if(readString.equals(""))
                for(int i = 0; i < deckNum; i++){
                    decks.put(i, new Deck(cardNum));
                }

                for(int key : decks.keySet()){
                    System.out.println("Deck # "+ key + " " +decks.get(key).toString());
                        if(key >= 52)
                            key = key + cardNum;
                        else if(key == 51)
                            System.out.println("All GONE!");
                }
            if(console.hasNextLine())
                readString = console.nextLine();
            else
                readString = null;
        }
    }   


    /**
     * Get number of decks 
     * @param console
     * @return
     */
    public static int getNumberOfDecks(Scanner console){
        int tempNumDecks = 0;
        boolean isOk = false;

        System.out.println("How many decks would you like to use?");

        do{
            try{
                String userInput = console.nextLine();
                tempNumDecks = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println ("Invalid input. Enter a number > 0");
                    System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than 0:");
            }
            isOk = true;
        }while(isOk == false);
        return tempNumDecks;
    }

    /**
     * Get number of cards
     * @param console
     * @return
     */
    public static int getNumberOfCards(Scanner console){
        int tempNumCards = 0;
        boolean isOk = false;

        System.out.println("How many cards would you like to deal?");

        do{
            try{
                String userInput = console.nextLine();
                tempNumCards = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

                if(tempNumCards <= 0) {
                    System.out.println ("Invalid input. Enter a number > 0");
                } else{
                    isOk = true;
                }//end else
            }//end try
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than 0:");
            }//end catch
        }while(isOk == false);
        return tempNumCards;
    }//end getNumberOfCards()
    }
```

Deck class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;


public class Deck {
    /** Cards instance **/
    private List<Card> cards;

    /** Random generator **/
    private Random r;

       public Deck(int numberOfCards)
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>(numberOfCards);

        int tempCardIndex = 0;

        for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
             {
               cards.add( new Card(a,b) );
             }
        }

        /** Shuffle this deck **/
        shuffle(cards);

        /** Slice the deck by our number of cards **/
        cards = cards.subList(0, numberOfCards);
    }

    /**
     *  Shuffle a list 
     * @param list
     */
    public void shuffle(List<Card> list) {
        if (r == null) {
            r = new Random();
        }
        shuffle(list, r);
    }

/**
 * Shuffle a list with Random rnd
 * @param list
 * @param rnd
 */
    public void shuffle(List<Card> list, Random rnd) {
        int size = list.size();

            Object[] arr = list.toArray();

            // Shuffle array
            for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
                swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

            // Dump array back into list
            ListIterator<Card> it = list.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                it.next();
                it.set((Card) arr[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap elements in List
     * @param list
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    public void swap(List<Card> list, int i, int j) {
        final List l = list;
        l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
    }

    /**
     * Swap Elements in Array
     * @param arr
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    private static void swap(Object[] arr, int i, int j) {
        Object tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Draw a card 
     * @return
     */
    public Card drawFromDeck()
    {      
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    /** Get total Cards 
     * 
     * @return cards size
     */
    public int getTotalCards()
    {
        return cards.size();
    }

    /**
     * to String override
     */
    public String toString(){
        return cards.toString();
    }

}
```

Card Class:

```
public class Card
{
   private int rank, suit;

   private final String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
   private final String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };


   public Card(int suit, int rank)
   {
       this.rank=rank;
       this.suit=suit;
   }

   public @Override String toString()
   {
         return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
   }

   public int getRank() {
        return rank;
   }

   public int getSuit() {
       return suit;
   }

}
```

So this prints a hashmap of the user specified amount of cards in a user specified amount of decks.

Like so:

```
Deck # 0 [Jack of hearts, 3 of spades, 7 of spades, 6 of hearts]
Deck # 1 [6 of hearts, 9 of clubs, King of spades, 2 of clubs]
Deck # 2 [5 of spades, King of clubs, Queen of clubs, King of spades]
Deck # 3 [5 of spades, 6 of hearts, 9 of clubs, 5 of diamonds]
```

It does this every time the user presses enter. My problem is, I want it to stop allowing the user to draw more cards from the deck(s) when all of the cards from each of the decks runs out. Is this possible? I have been told by a colleague to use a boolean somehow to make this work but I'm stumped.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: or you could simply ignore all replies and answers to your question... :/

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call the method that checks the number of cards, `getTotalCards()` **before** calling `drawFromDeck()`.  Then if it's 0, you know that no cards are left.

Note that with such questions, it's always best to show us your attempt to solve it as part of your question, else you're just cheating yourself out of a learning opportunity, and preventing us from seeing what may be wrong with your logic.